# Second adjoint of the canonical embedding

Tags: functional-analysis, banach-spaces

Suppose that $X$ is a Banach space. Denote by $\kappa_X$ the canonical embedding of $X$ into $X^{**}$. Do we always have
$$(\kappa_X)^{**} = \kappa_{X^{**}}? $$

Comment: A terse Question, like a terse Answer, puts an undue burden on most Readers to unpack what is being said.  While you've defined $\kappa_X$ as a mapping from $X$ into the double dual $X^{**}$, following this definition literally would make $\kappa_{X^{**}}$ a map from $X^{**}$ into *its* double dual.  At a minimum I recommend improving the Question by acknowledging what "unstated" assumptions you are willing to make about fixing up domains and codomains.

Comment: @hardmath I'm finding it confusing to work out, but there are no unstated assumptions that I can see, he means exactly what he said, literally. $\kappa_{X^{**}}:X^{**}\to X^{****}$ and $\kappa_X^{**}:X^{**}\to X^{****}$.

Comment: First reaction is yes, we have two canonical embeddings from $X^{**}$ into $X^{****}$, how could they be different? Then I say to myself we should be able to settle this by just working through the chain of definitions. And then when I start trying to do that I see why you posted the question... Maybe it will be clear after lunch.

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich: That's how I unpack it as well, but I mean that the (new) user should try and expedite responses by doing a bit more by way of explanation.  It would be "context" for those inclined to close very short Questions quickly.

Comment: @hardmath I guess - when you say "At a minimum I recommend improving the Question by acknowledging what "unstated" assumptions you are willing to make about fixing up domains and codomains. " it sounds as though you're referring to unstated assumptions about fixing up the domain and codomain - there's no fixing up needed.

Comment: A comment for the people that hardmath fears tend to close short questions quickly: The question _is_ perfectly precisely stated; I don't see any need for additional "context", it means exactly what it says. If anyone feels inclined to close because he hasn't shown us his work so far, I suggest you try to work it out - surely his work so far is the same as mine and as what yours will be: a page of unpacking this and that definition that seems like it should be enough but doesn't quite seem to get there...

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich:  For me the crux of "unstated" assumptions is how $(\kappa_X)^{**}$ gets defined as $(\kappa_X^*)^*$.  Very standard in functional analysis, but Isn't this what makes "the chain of definitions" torturous to follow?

Comment: @hardmath What made it hard for me was that it's false.

Comment: @hardmath Was in a hurry just then. Seriously: Is there a context where $T^{**}$ means something other than ${(T^*)}^*$?

Comment: One quick way to see why you might not expect this to be true is that the dual $T^*:Y^*\to X^*$ of any bounded linear map $T:X\to Y$ between Banach spaces is always continuous from the weak* topology to the weak* topology.  So $(\kappa_X)^{**}$ is automatically weak*-weak* continuous.  But $\kappa_{X^{**}}$ doesn't know about the fact that $X^{**}$ is a dual space so its definition doesn't involve the weak* topology, so you probably can't expect it to be weak*-weak* continuous.

Comment: @EricWofsey Thanks. Actually that occurred to me, but it seemed so clear it "must" be true I assumed that the weak*-weak* continuity just happened miraculously. Turns out that $\kappa_{X^{**}}\kappa_X=\kappa_X^{**}\kappa_X$; there was _something_ true behind that feeling that it must be so...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. Not that that makes any sense to me, but no. In fact it turns out that $\kappa_{X^{**}}=\kappa_X^{**}$ if and only if $X$ is reflexive.

**In fact** the truth behind my erroneous feeling that the two must be equal in general is this: $$\kappa_{X^{**}}\kappa_X=\kappa_X^{**}\kappa_X.$$

**Proofs:** Writing $x\in X$, $x^*\in X^*$, etc.:

If you unpack two definitions you see the question is whether $$x^{***}(x^{**})=x^{**}(\kappa_X^*x^{***}).$$

If $X$ is not reflexive, choose $x^{***}\ne0$ so $x^{***}(\kappa_X x)=0$ for all $x$. That says precisely that $\kappa_X^*x^{***}=0$. But there exists $x^{**}$ with $x^{***}(x^{**})\ne0$.

Of course it must be true if $X$ is reflexive. But I thought it must be true in general, and actually writing down a proof took me a few minutes, so here it is:

The proof that $\kappa_{X^{**}}\kappa_X=\kappa_X^{**}\kappa_X$ in general is just unpacking definitions:

$$\kappa_{X^{**}}\kappa_X(x)(x^{***})=x^{***}(\kappa_X(x)),$$
while

$$\kappa_X^{**}\kappa_X(x)(x^{***})=\kappa_X(x)(\kappa_X^*(x^{***}))
=\kappa_X^*(x^{***})(x)=x^{***}(\kappa_X(x)).$$

And now if $X$ is reflexive then $\kappa_X$ is an isomorphism, so it follows that $\kappa_{X^{**}}=\kappa_X^{**}$.

If there are no typos here it's a friggin miracle.

---

**Or** do this:

**Exercise** Whether $X$ is reflexive or not, $\kappa_X^*\kappa_{X^*}x^*=x^*$. Show that this implies $\kappa_{X^{**}}=\kappa_X^{**}$ if $X$ is reflexive.

Comment: Thank you, this is most helpful.